# Drag and Drop QTreeWidgetItem to QGraphicsView with custom data

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsscene, qtreewidget

I've a class containing a `QTreeWidget`, where I have some `QTreeWidgetItem`.

I want to drag and drop a `QTreeWidgetItem` into a `QGraphicsScene`, in order to create an object in there. The object is a rectangle with the text of the `QTreeWidgetItem` in there.

I was able to perform the drag and drop operation, and I've my `dropEvent` virtual method for handling it. It receives the drop event, but I'm not be able to retrieve information about the original `QTreeWidgetItem`.

This is the code that I've used to initialize the `QTreeWidget`:

```
m_nodeList = new QTreeWidget(this);
m_nodeList->setColumnCount(2);
m_nodeList->setHeaderLabels({ NameLabel, CategoryLabel });
m_nodeList->setDragEnabled(true);
m_nodeList->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragOnly);
```

The `dropEvent` overridden method in my `Scene` subclass of `QGraphicsScene` is the following one:

```
void Scene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent* event) {
  event->acceptProposedAction();

  for (const auto& it : event->mimeData()->formats()) {
    std::string f = it.toStdString();
    int i = 0;
  }
  std::string t = event->mimeData()->text().toStdString();
  std::string on = event->mimeData()->objectName().toStdString();
}
```

`f` contains `application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist`, while other strings are empty.

How can I retrieve information about the `QTreeWidgetItem` that I've dragged into the `QGraphicsScene`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DND of models uses an internal Qt format so a possible solution is to use a dummymodel:

```cpp
void Scene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent* event) {
    event->acceptProposedAction();
    if(event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist")){
        QStandarditemmodel dummy_model;
        if(dummy_model.dropMimeData(event->mimeData(), event->dropAction(), 0, 0, QModelIndex()){
            QModelIndex index = dummy_model.index(0, 0);
            qDebug() << index.data();
        }
    }
}
```